# (nologin) root and id X re-spawning

Tags: rhel, login, console, init

Today I faced a strange issue on one of the test server. Server was set to Runlevel 5. But it didnt work and system changed to runlevel 3.

It was showing "init: Id "x" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes" and also on Text Console it was showing

(nologin) root :

Even though no one changed the password and i insert the correct password still it was not accepting and password and jumped back to prompt.

So then i reboot the system to Single user mode but it was just jumping to level 3 and kept asking for password. So I had to reinstall the system.

But what might the cause these errors.

```
1) init: Id "x" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes --- I believe I can solve it
2) (nologin) root --- This is tricky one
```